# how to display value of mysql sum query

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I am trying to grab the total amount of sales made for a a single month

```
$aug11 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(price) FROM table WHERE sales_date LIKE '08/%/2011' ");
```

when I echo `$aug11` I get a resource id# error. I also tried to do this

```
$test1 = mysql_fetch_array($aug11);
```

and when I echo `$test1` it just says "Array".

Is it absolutely necessary to place a GROUP by sales_date in the original query and then have a while loop that grabs the array and lets me echo the values?

I don't really need any other value except the sum of 'price' for the month of August.

Can someone please explain to me how I can display the value I need without a while loop?

Comment: you are fetching array, thus test1 is array.. consider var_dump($test1); or $test1[0] to access the value you are looking for..

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array   when a function is called 'fetch_array', perhaps you should assume that just maybe it actually returns (surprise!) an array.

Comment: **1.** Salesdate should be a date, not a varchar **2.** don't use `like`, use `where sales_date BETWEEN '2011-08-01' AND '2011-08-31'`  **3.** put an index on sales_date if you want fast queries.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! We could've done without the snide condescending tone of some of them (surprised Marc B?), but the help is still very much appreciated. have a great weekend guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this to get the sum value

`$test1[0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $test1[0]; // returns the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

$aug11 is not a query string, it is the result of a query.  When you fetch an array from the result, it is an array of values, not a scalar.  I think you want to do this:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(price) FROM table WHERE sales_date LIKE '08/%/2011'";
$aug11 = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($aug11);
$test1 = $aug11[0];
```